# Lifts of Spherical Space Forms and conjugation isometries

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, isometry

I want to prove that 
ϕ
: 
Sn/G1 →
Sn/G2
is an isometry iff 
G1
and 
G2
are conjugate in 
O(n+1)
(where 
G1
and 
G2
are groups of isometries acting freely on the sphere 
Sn
). I know that 
ϕ
lifts to an isometry of 
Sn
and so is in O(n+1). But what to do after that? How does this imply that 
G1
and 
G2
are conjugate in 
O(n+1)
and vice versa?

Comment: Is $\phi$ some pre-defined mapping, or do you mean _there exists_ an isometry $\phi:S^{n}/G_{1} \to S^{n}/G_{2}$ iff..."?

Comment: I mean to say that any two spherical space forms are isometric iff their respective groups are conjugate in O(n+1)